# Java BatchUpdateException in SQL processing

Tags: java, mysql

The following code gives a `BatchUpdateException` and I have no idea why.

```
public void createContactmoment(Document document) {
    try {
        c = MySqlDAOFactory.getInstance().getConnection();
        //
        c.setAutoCommit(false);
        //
        String sql = "insert into index(iddocument,chapter,chapterdate)"
                + "values (?,?,?)";
        //
        prest = c.prepareStatement(sql);
        //
        int count = 1;
        //Formatter for the time
        DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
        //
         while (count <= Integer.parseInt(document.getTeachingWeeks())
            || count == document.getAllDates().size()
            || count == document.getContactMomentList().size()) {
            //
            if (MysqlDocumentDAO.getInstance().findByName(
                    document.getName()) == -1)
                return;
            //
            prest.setInt(1,MysqlDocumentDAO.getInstance().findByName(
            document.getName()));
            if (document.getContactMomentList().get(count) != null)
            prest.setString(2,document.getContactMomentList().get(count));
            else
            prest.setString(2, "No contactmoment found, but expected");
            //
            if (document.getAllDates().get(count) != null)
                prest.setString(3,(format.print(document.getAllDates().get(count))));
            else
            prest.setString(3, "Na date found, but expected");
            //
            prest.addBatch();
            //
            count++;
        }
        //
        prest.executeBatch();
        c.commit();
        //
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JdbcLogging.info("Dit trad op bij het uitvoeren van de batchtaak (contactMoments)"+ " :" + e);
    } finally {
        MySqlConnectionFactory.getInstance().closeStatement(prest);
        MySqlConnectionFactory.getInstance().closeConnection(c);
    }
}
```

The error I see in my log is :

> INFO JdbcLogging:25 - Dit trad op bij het uitvoeren van de batchtaak (contactMoments) :java.sql.BatchUpdateException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index(iddocument,chapter,chapterdate)values (44,'Examen; * Verdedigen project','' at line 1

So it seems that in the last update I'm missing some data.  The data I want to write does excist (I checked with a system printline.

Any suggestions would be more then welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`index` is a reserved word and should have not used for a table name. In your query put the word ``index`` in *`back quotes`* and execute then it should be working.

```
String sql = "insert into `index`(iddocument,chapter,chapterdate) values (?,?,?)";
```

Comment: I renamed the table end refactored my code and it does the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a space between the 2 SQL lines - the `)` and the word `values` should be separated...

```
String sql = "insert into index (iddocument,chapter,chapterdate) "
           + "values (?,?,?)";
```

Similarly, it wouldn't hurt to try adding a space between `index` and `(` - it just depends on how picky the SQL interpreter is.

Also, `index` is a bad name for a table, as index has special meaning in many databases. I assume that `index` is the name of your table, and you aren't actually trying to insert data into an index!?

Finally, not sure if you need a `;` at the end of the statement? It isn't usually required when building up the code like this, so maybe try without it first, and perhaps add it later if you're still having problems.

Comment: not having a space after `)` and `values` is not an error. And `;` is part of JAVA syntax for end of a statement.

Comment: Well, in the exception output it shows `chapterdate)values` (ie, without a space), so I'm wondering whether the SQL interpreter is actually expecting a space there? Its not technically an error, however it does make it harder for the interpreter to correctly work out what the SQL statement is supposed to be doing.

Comment: exception trace actually starts from `index(id...` means error is with or before `index`

Comment: On that note, the first full 'word' of the exception trace is `index(iddocument,chapter,chapterdate)values`. I know that most interpreters should identify the brackets as being a separator, but I would take this as a definite assurance. If its just seeing this as a single word, which in this case would represent a table name, then its going to throw up.